# Laravel another way of appending to model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an api Laravel. In my message model I've append the following:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['subscribed'];


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSubscribedAttribute()
{
    return $this->isSubscribedBy();
}
```

`IsSubscribedBy();` lives in a trait that looks like this:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function isSubscribedBy()
{
    return $this->subscriptions()
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->exists();
}
```

This is working but doing it like this has the `n + 1` problem and I can't load the messages in algolia with `php artisan scout:import "App\Messages\Message"` that obviously throws an error (because no one is signed in but it's looking for someone: `Auth::user()->id):`

> [ErrorException]
>    Trying to get property of non-object

So are there better ways? I already tried fractal but then I still have the `n + 1` problem.

---EDIT---

I'm returning like this:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function index()
{
    return Message::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(10);
}
```

So for each message it will exec this query:

```
$this->subscriptions()
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->exists();
```

Comment: I would inject the `user_id`, that way you could get any users subscriptions not just the logged in user's.

Comment: i think perhaps you misunderstood my question. I need the subscription status from the authenticated user. If I send the ```user_id```  back then I don't know if the user is subscribed.

Comment: No I didn't misunderstand. What I mean is I don't think you should use this as an attribute, I think it should be a function where you pass in a user id. So if you are in a view and you need to check if the logged in user is subscribed it would be `{{ $message->userSubscribed(Auth::user()->id) }}`. I try to avoid using global state inside a function as it makes it very hard to unit test.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I've not mentioned in my question that it's an api (I use vue.js for the frontend). So then that is not possible. (I've changed my question)

Comment: I'm not sure what algolia is, so if you have to have it as an attribute then you probably need to first check if a user is not logged in and return false no matter what if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user isn't logged in at all then obviously they can't be subscribed. So you could do something like this:

```
public function isSubscribedBy()
{
    if(!Auth::check()) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->subscriptions()
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->exists();
}
```

Or if you need something other than `false` like `null` just return that instead.

Ok figured out how to eager load it, first you need to constrain your eager loading to the current user:

```
return Message::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->with(['subscriptions'=> function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
}])->paginate(10);
```

Then it eager loads only the current users subscriptions for the messages. Now in your attribute getter you need to access the collection that has been eager loaded not eloquent getter. You do this simply by removing the `()` on `subscriptions()` and using collection methods instead of eloquent methods (which most of the time look exactly the same). So your function can look like this:

```
public function isSubscribedBy()
{
    return ($this->subscriptions->count() > 0);
}
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Thanks but then I still have the ```n + 1``` problem I guess. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Yeah not sure exactly how you will solve that, I would need to see where you are loading your whole list of messages. You can use eager loading normally to solve the `n+1` problem.

Comment: In my edit above you can see how I send back the messages. Any idea if it's possible to eager load one value?

Comment: Thanks!! You are awesome!

Comment: ```->withCount(['subscriptions'=> function ($query) {
          $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
         }])```